# React bind(this, value) in opposite order on function declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an onClick handler function that passes in the click event and index arguments to the function.

However, turns out I have to declare things in opposite order.. as such:

```
render(){
    return(
       <button onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, index)}Click Me</button>
    )
}

deleteItem(index, e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(deleteTodo(index));
}
```

This works without issue.  But why must `this` and `index` be switched in deleteItem()?  Is this documented somewhere I am unaware of?

Comment: what do you mean switched? the syntax is `fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: What do you mean by switched? Are you thinking that `e` and `this` are the same thing? `this` is not passed into `deleteItem`.  The bind call does not call the `deleteItem` function.  It binds the context and sets the first parameter to `index`. Then when the button is pressed the function gets called and the event is passed in as the second parameter.  I suggest reading up on bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: this does not refer to the event argument as you might think. this is a reference to the component. If not bound to the component, deleteItem is bound to the button.

Comment: Thanks guys!  I was completely wrong in my assumption that the default `e` argument was the referring to `this` in the call.
I am still a bit foggy on why `index` is first, and the event argument is second in `deleteItem(index, e)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` and `index` are not being switched. What you're seeing is the difference between using `bind` to bind a `this` value and calling the function directly.

In short, if you were to call the function directly, like so:

```
<button onClick={this.deleteItem}Click Me</button>
```

You would get the arguments in the order in which you declared them in the function. But, as you obviously know, calling the function in this way leaves you with a `this` variable referring to the context in which the event handler was called, not the actual class you have declared.

What you're doing instead is calling `this.deleteItem.bind`, which is necessary to ensure that the `this` variable is properly bound when it is called in the context of the event.

The better way to do this is the way shown in the [React documentation on ES6 classes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes): bind the event handler in the constructor of the class.

For example,

```
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

By binding the event handler method in the constructor, it is clearer, and you don't have to worry about the context when you use it.

**EDIT**

Sometimes, you need to pass specific data to your event handler. This is possible using the constructor binding method here. Just do something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.myHandler = this.myHandler.bind(this);
}

myHandler(importantValue, event) {
    console.log(importantValue); // will log 'pass this value!'
    // and you have access to the event object, if you pass it along
    // if you don't need the event object, then just leave it out
}

render() {
    <div onClick={(event) => { this.myHandler('pass this value!', event); }>
        Click Me!
    </div>
}
```

By adding an anonymous function as your event handler in the onClick property for your element, you can do anything you want!

Comment: I've used the ES6 class constructor method in other classes I'm using in the app, but in this case I need to pass in a specific index that is being clicked on.  So I don't think you can bind event handlers in the constructor in cases like this (since each click has a different index).  Perhaps I'm wrong! :)

But alas, my understanding of what exactly I was binding was a bit off regardless as seen in some comments!

Comment: this definitely clears it up for me.  Up-vote for you!  I appreciate the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for bind(). bind() fixes/binds the context (this keyword) of the function to the object specfied in the first argument, and the rest of the arguments are *prepended* to the bound function. That's why index appears before event.